# How does the title apply to the characters in "The Matrix Resurrections?"

Tags: the-matrix

At the end of *The Matrix Revolutions*, it is clearly seen that Trinity died in the ship trying to reach the machine city, and Neo died after the fight.

In *Resurrections* we see that

> The Analyst resurrected Neo and Trinity to use them as power sources.

Assuming the machines found a way to reconstruct dead human bodies,  how could they insert a soul or whatever causes a human body to be alive?

Comment: Well, the concept of a soul is just an idea that many people have, but basically just speculation. Maybe there is no such thing as a soul. If it would be possible to make a copy of your body with all its molecules it isn't that unlkely that it will live just fine. PS, I didn't see the movie, so I don't know if souls are mentioned in the Matrix

Comment: FYI I removed the unnecessary/overly specific tag.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Why, the question is specific to the movie.

Comment: Of course, the “real world” is just another simulation- its turtles all the way down.

Comment: @user10191234 films needn't have their own tag. Take a look around (Harry potter, lord of the rings, star wars etc) and you'll notice that's not required.

Comment: @IvoBeckers: that's especially true in the Matrix universe where there are sentient programs. It would be hard to claim that Neo has a soul but Smith does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lana Wachowski explains why they’re back](https://youtu.be/rtLbghso0Zc), starting about the 8m mark:

> My brain has always reached into my imagination and one night, I was crying and I couldn't sleep, and suddenly my brain exploded this whole story. And I couldn't have my mom and dad, I couldn't talk to my mom, yet suddenly I had Neo and Trinity, arguably the two most important characters in my life. It was immediately comforting to have these two characters again.
> And it's super simple, you can look at it and say, 'Ah yeah, these two people die, bring these two people back to life, and oh doesn't that feel good?' And yeah, it did.

To Wachowski, it is “super simple” — these two people die so bring them back to life.

The Machines do this by using “resurrection pods.” However, they work, they produce Wachowski’s “super simple” result of resurrection; how the soul gets crammed back into their bodies is the stuff of speculative internet sites and not germane to Wachowski’s story.

As an aside, regarding the *Matrix’s* concept and handling of “souls,” it appears very little in the trilogy. A word-search of the word “soul” in available internet scripts and transcripts reveals the word never appears in *The Matrix*, once in *Reloaded*, and zero in *Revolutions*.

And its use in *Reloaded* is a simple quotation by Choi from Thomas Paine’s “The American Crisis”:

> Well, these are the times that try men’s souls. Here’s to victory.

Its context then is not to suggest any deep metaphysical meaning of souls within the *Matrix* universe or settle how souls may return to resurrected bodies, but rather serves as a call back to the American Revolution.

This suggests that the very idea of souls as you describe as the basis of your question may be a shallow or incidental concept to the meaning or understanding of the *Matrix* films.